# Windows XP to Windows 7 migration - Registry update

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-registry

In Windows XP an application uses the following to read the username:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

While in Windows 7 same is mapped to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

Is it possible for Windows 7 to update this registry setting entry based on the user that is logged in at that time? I have tried to enter the required user names but it does not pick it up.

Comment: Say what? What are you trying to do? Why are you messing around in the registry?

Comment: It is required for an application to work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the job of the application to read the correct registry key based on the OS?

Comment: It worked on XP  just not when i try to use the app in windows 7 it has issues.

Comment: Does the vendor provide any kind of support? It might be best to ask them.

Comment: The vendor advised to add the user ids to the second reg key and it didnt work. This worked with the first reg key under xp. Does windows 7 log the user ID somewhere so I can direct them to pick it up there.

Comment: Vendor has agreed to retool the application. Thanks all.